# Using SQL Where clauses on an array column

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, where-clause

A column contains a list of arrays in a table in `hadoop`. When the array has no data the column has the following `[]`.

I am trying to return a list of unique IDs where `[]` does not appear in that column. I can't use `<>` or `!=`.

I also tried returning rows where the character length is greater than 2, but this didn't work.

How can I return rows that do not contain `[]`?

Comment: there is a function `size(Array<T>)` to check the size of an array. check that it is > 0.

Comment: Related tutorial / documentation: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-BuiltInFunctions